# Variance of the sum of random variables

Tags: random-variables, covariance, means, variance

For a vector (X,Y,Z) with a multivariate normal distribution, $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are given as the following:

$
\mu =
\begin{pmatrix}
76\\ 42\\ 22
\end{pmatrix}
$
, and
$
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 16 &  5 & -16 \\
  5 & 36 &   0 \\
-16 &  0 &  25 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

However, two new variables, A and B, have been defined:

$
A=X-Z, \ \ B=X-Y
$

If X, Y, and Z are independent and random, the mean and variance for the new variables can be found:

$
E[A] = E[X-Z] = E[X] - E[Z] \\
Var(A) = Var(X-Z) = Var(X) - Var(Z)
$

However, we cannot assume independence. How can you find the mean and variance of A and B?

Comment: Why do you say X, Y and Z are independent?

Comment: How did you get that formula for the variance, variance is always non negative. $\operatorname{var} (X-Z) = \operatorname{var} X + \operatorname{var} Z$ if $X,Z$ are independent.

Comment: @LinAlg good question—I made that assumption mistakenly. I'm correcting the question now.

Comment: Your title is inconsistent with the last statement.

Comment: Expectation is linear, so the mean is trivial.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for the correction, and yes, I thought that would be the case for the means. I'm still stumped on variance.

Comment: If they are independent, variances do not subtract.  They add.

Comment: @Paul I just amended the question to clarify how I had interpreted the property. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Variance is not linear.  It does not work this way.  As @copper.hat said, variance is always non-negative, while your formula can easily give a negative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all follows from linearity.

Let me use $W$ to represent the three dimensional rv. and $L$ is a linear map.

Then $E[LW] = L E[W] = L \mu$.

For variance:
\begin{eqnarray}
E[(LW -E[LW])((LW -E[LW])^T ] &=& E[(L(W-\mu))(L(W-\mu))^T ] \\
&=&
 L E[(W-\mu)(W-\mu)^T ] L^T \\
&=& L \Sigma L^T
\end{eqnarray}

Then $A= L_1 W$, with $L_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} $
and $B = L_2 W$  with $L_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} $.

Grinding through the computations gives

> Mean of $54$ and variance of $73$ for $A$, Mean of $34$ and variance of $42$ for $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Means are linear, so $E[A]=E[X]-E[Z]$ whether or not they independent.

Variance is more complicated.  Instead, you get
$$Var(A)=Var(X)+Var(Z)-2Cov(X,Z)$$.

Comment: So because A is defined as X-Z, we subtract twice the covariance rather than add? And the summation of each correlated variables' variance will always be positive?

Comment: Correct on both counts.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding correctly in this case, would $Var(A) = 16 + 25 -2 (-16) = 73$ or $Var(A) = 16 + 25 + 2 (-16) = 9$?